# Routing between 3 LANs

Tags: networking, routing

I'm using 4 Ubuntu desktop machines. 2 of the machines are a gateway and a router.

The gateway has two interfaces:

> > ens33 with address 192.168.1.1/24
> >
> > ens38 with address 172.20.208.1/24

the router has two interfaces:

> > ens33 with address 172.20.208.2/24
> >
> > ens38 with address 10.0.0.1/16

the third machine is a client with a single interface:

> > ens33 with address 192.168.1.2/24

The forth machine is an httpd server with a single interface:

> > ens33 with address 10.0.0.2/16

There are 3 LANs as you can see, I've tested with a ping inside each LAN for validity as well as outside the LAN. My problem is, for example if I want to ping from **172.20.208.2** to **192.168.1.2** that are from different LANs; I get a destination host unreachable eventhough I enabled ip forwarding and set a route to the gw **172.20.208.1** for packets of destination **192.168.1.0** with the following command:

> > route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 172.20.208.1

pinging 192.168.1.1 from 172.20.208.2 and vice versa works fine.

What route(s) should I actually make so I can ping all the LANs?